# JQuery Mobile swiperight event fires previously fired listview elements

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm trying to use the 'swiperight' event to delete listview items, but it seems that the event will fire also for previously fired elements. I've been struggling with this for a while trying to debug and figure out whether it is a scope or bubbling issue, but I literally have no idea.

[here is a gif to illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06qHy.gif)

here is the code:

```
var $task;

$("#todolist").on("swiperight", ">li", function() {
    $task = $(this);
    $task.animate({left: "30%"}, confirmAndDelete($task));
});

function confirmAndDelete($task) {
    $("#confirm").popup("open");
    $("#confirm #yes").on("tap", function() {
        $task.animate({left: "70%"}, function() {
            $task.remove();
        });
    });
    $("#confirm #cancel").on("tap", function() {
        $task.animate({left: "-=30%"});
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding new tap handlers to the yes and cancel buttons each time, so either add an off() to remove the previous handler or just create them once outside of confirmAndDelete:

```
var $task;

$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

    $("#todolist").on("swiperight", ">li", function() {
        $task = $(this);
        $task.animate({left: "30%"}, function(){
            $("#confirm").popup("open");
        });
    });

    $("#confirm #yes").on("tap", function() {
        $task.animate({left: "70%"}, function() {
            $task.remove();
        });
    });
    $("#confirm #cancel").on("tap", function(e) {
        $task.animate({left: "-=30%"});
    });

});
```